# Golang time.duration format for C# TimeSpan

Tags: c#, go

I recently did a bit of Golang and really enjoyed the format for *time.duration*. For [example](https://pkg.go.dev/time#example-ParseDuration), "1d2h3s". I could not find a way to use this format with the C# TimeSpan class. Any ideas?

Comment: Your example omits minutes -- is that intentional because the minutes are zero?  If so, you'll probably have to parse and format this value yourself.  If you actually wanted to include minutes, you could just use `@"d\dh\hm\ms\s"` as your format string.

Comment: @KirkWoll The way I understand it, OP wants to do it the other way around. Formatted string -> TimeSpan value.

Comment: @Despacito2, the format string is bidirectional (`TimeSpan.ParseExact(...)`)

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know! Anyways, my answer has the format you were looking for.

Comment: @Kirk Woll If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Despacito2, you have me confused with Joniboy.  Cheers.

Comment: My appologies ^^ @Joniboy, If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to exist a formatting implementation the way you found it on Golang but in case you prefer it that way I wrote a custom method to allow you that:

```
public static class TimeSpanHelper
{
    private static List<(string Abbreviation, TimeSpan InitialTimeSpan)> timeSpanInfos = new List<(string Abbreviation, TimeSpan InitialTimeSpan)>
    {
            ("y", TimeSpan.FromDays(365)), // Year
            ("M", TimeSpan.FromDays(30)), // Month
            ("w", TimeSpan.FromDays(7)), // Week
            ("d", TimeSpan.FromDays(1)), // Day
            ("h", TimeSpan.FromHours(1)), // Hour
            ("m", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)), // Minute
            ("s", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)), // Second
            ("t", TimeSpan.FromTicks(1)) // Tick
    };

    public static TimeSpan ParseDuration(string format)
    {
        var result = timeSpanInfos
            .Where(timeSpanInfo => format.Contains(timeSpanInfo.Abbreviation))
            .Select(timeSpanInfo => timeSpanInfo.InitialTimeSpan * int.Parse(new Regex(@$"(\d+){timeSpanInfo.Abbreviation}").Match(format).Groups[1].Value))
            .Aggregate((accumulator, timeSpan) => accumulator + timeSpan);
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can use it in the following way:

```
var total = TimeSpanHelper.ParseDuration("1d2h3s");
```

**Note that there are built in implementations that allow you to achieve the same result:**

The `TimeSpan` struct has following constructor headers:

```
public TimeSpan(long ticks)

public TimeSpan(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)

public TimeSpan(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds)

public TimeSpan(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)
```

Therefore we can C#ify your example in the following way:

```
var total = new TimeSpan(1, 2, 0, 3);
```

Alternatively we can use some static methods on the `TimeSpan` struct that allow us to put in a value for a specific time period:

```
public static TimeSpan FromDays(double value)

public static TimeSpan FromHours(double value)

public static TimeSpan FromMinutes(double value)

public static TimeSpan FromSeconds(double value)

public static TimeSpan FromMilliseconds(double value)

public static TimeSpan FromTicks(long value)
```

So we could also do:

```
var total = TimeSpan.FromDays(1) + TimeSpan.FromHours(2) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
```